# Azure database for MySQL - slow massive inserts

Tags: mysql, azure

For PoC, I have created Azure database for MySQL with 4 vCores and 20GB of RAM. I'm loading Litecoin blockchain data there using Python and SQL Alchemy. There will be no more than 200 million rows in the biggest table. Each block is added in one batch, using SQL Alchemy's `bulk_save_objects` method. Non-primary indexes are either don't exists or single non-primary index for block number exists in a table. The problem is that the load is quite slow with 4 parallel worker processes feeding the data. What I see is that it works in bursts - 20-30 blocks are fed to MySQL in few seconds, then it waits 10-25 seconds and "burst" repeats.

On a contrary, in the office I have fast server with plenty of resources, where such load does not show "bursts" - it just linearly loads the blocks. However, despite the available resources, MySQL does not consume more than 18GB of RAM, and not more than 2 vCores. I have adjusted only few parameters of MySQL on my local (non-Azure) server:

```
key_buffer_size = 1024M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16G
innodb_log_file_size = 2048M
```

`key_buffer_size` is not editable in Azure console. `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is set to 16GB by default there. And `innodb_log_file_size` is again not editable there. I did not edit any of the Azure MySQL parameters yet, don't want to make a mess there. I/O metric of MySQL in Azure shows 120% of usage.

Did anyone experience such behavior with MySQL in general, or better with Azure MySQL? Anything I can do to have linear processing of my inserts in Azure MySQL and in general to make it faster? Does Microsoft use slow HDDs? In my local server I have Samsung Evo SSDs in hardware RAID, maybe Microsoft uses some entry-level SSD disks or even mechanical HDDs? As Litecoin blockchain is not huge, I allocated only 116GB of HDD storage for the machine - maybe then Microsoft somehow shares that space with others (actually cloud is all about sharing) on entry level hardware?

First I was loading from machine in my office, but due to 140ms latency I rented VM in Azure and now I load from it. Machine is quite powerful there, so I may install MySQL there and compare - maybe if I run it on VM, it will be faster than using managed instance. But I want the current experiment with managed MySQL to end before proceeding with the next.

Here is my script which creates tables:

```
CREATE TABLE ltc_blocks
(
    number int NOT NULL, 
    block_hash char(64) NOT NULL,
    size int,
    block_version bigint,
    previous_block_hash char(64),
    merkle_root char(64),
    block_timestamp int NOT NULL,
    bits bigint,
    nonce bigint,
    difficulty real,
    CONSTRAINT PK_blocks_number PRIMARY KEY (number)
) ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;


CREATE TABLE ltc_transactions
(
    id bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    tx_id char(64) NOT NULL,
    tx_hash char(64) NOT NULL,
    tx_timestamp int NOT NULL, 
    block_number int NOT NULL,
    tx_index int NOT NULL,
    is_coinbase bit NOT NULL,
    is_segwit bit NOT NULL,
    n_inputs int NOT NULL,
    n_outputs int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_transactions_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;

CREATE INDEX idx_block_no on ltc_transactions (block_number);


CREATE TABLE ltc_participants
(
    id bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    block_number int NOT NULL,
    transaction_id bigint NOT NULL,
    tx_hash char(64), -- only for outputs
    p_address varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    p_value bigint NOT NULL,
    p_index int NOT NULL,
    p_role tinyint NOT NULL,
    p_type tinyint,
    CONSTRAINT PK_participant_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;

CREATE INDEX idx_p_block_role on ltc_participants (p_role, block_number);


CREATE TABLE ltc_raw_inputs
(
    source_tx_hash char(64) NOT NULL,
    source_output_index int NOT NULL,
    block_number integer NOT NULL,
    spending_tx_id bigint NOT NULL,
    i_index int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_raw_input_id PRIMARY KEY (source_tx_hash, source_output_index)
) ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;

CREATE INDEX idx_input_block ON ltc_raw_inputs(block_number);
```

Comment: OK, it appeared that storage size is directly connected to IOPS Azure would allow. I have increased storage 3 times and got IOPS limit increased 3 times. Will see if it affects performance - no effect so far, maybe I need to restart the server.

Comment: Restarted the server and it started to work without bursts. You get what you pay for, no magic. Sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: For future readers - even with storage size and thus IOPS increased 5 times, at certain stage of the data loading (take into account that blockchain technology attracted people's attention in late 2017 and we saw massive increase in number of transactions) it still goes into "bursts" mode, though not so severe as with much lower storage size. However this is initial load, in normal operations we will be doing catch up of few blocks. If you would always have intensive loads, you may consider dedicated VM instead of Azure MySQL.